# 'Invalid' property type or designer bug?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an interface called

```
ISquare
```

There is a usercontrol MatrixGrid which has a public property

```
public List<List<ISquare>> Squares
{
    get { return (List<List<ISquare>>)GetValue(SquaresProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SquaresProperty);}
}
```

and I am able to bind to it in the designer for this usercontrol without any issue.

If I place a MatrixGrid in a window and try to bind to the Squares property, the designer throws an error

```
The member "Squares" is not recognized or accessible
```

and the Gui part of the designer shows

```
Invalid Markup, check the error list for more information
```

Running the program, all the bindings work properly and everything behaves without problems.

Is this a bug in the designer or is there a rule written down somewhere about this?

I'm running Visual Studio Express 2012 For Windows Desktop

I was able to duplicate it with the following code

TestControl.xaml.cs

```
public partial class TestControl : UserControl
{
    public TestControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static DependencyProperty
        TestProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyTest", typeof(List<List<Test>>), typeof(TestControl));
    public List<List<Test>> MyTest { get { return (List<List<Test>>)GetValue(TestProperty); } set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); } }
}
public interface Test {}
```

TestWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="simthing.TestWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:simthing"
    Title="TestWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <local:TestControl MyTest="{Binding Tests}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Error still persist once you rebuild your solution?

Comment: It does, and so does closing and reopening the solution, but as I said the error doesn't effect the build, just the designer

Comment: That's not really germane in the context of what I'm doing, which requires the 2-dimensionality that a nested list of lists of objects provides.  Imagine that they're IEnumerables or ObservableCollections if you must

Comment: in the test control property getter and setters are missing, xaml designer uses getter and setters to display properties via intellisence and hint some of the design time errors, however during runtime getvalue and setvalue methods are used from a dependency object.